# Insert Rows Using ROWNUM In Oracle

Tags: oracle, rownum

In my code I am trying to insert data in a for loop based on the row number. The reason I want to use it is because otherwise I get a "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error, because my select subqueries return more than one row, indeed and obviously I want to insert it one at a time.

```
declare
begin
for x in (select * from PilotKeyLookup) loop
if x.p2id != null then
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.nextval, (select p1id from PilotKeyLookup));
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.currval, (select p2id from PilotKeyLookup));
else
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.nextval, (select p1id from PilotKeyLookup));
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

And this is how I am trying to use rownum:

```
declare
begin
for x in (select * from PilotKeyLookup) loop
if x.p2id != null then
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.nextval, (select p1id from PilotKeyLookup where rownum = x));
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.currval, (select p2id from PilotKeyLookup where rownum = x));
else
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.nextval, (select p1id from PilotKeyLookup where rownum = x));
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

However, I get an "expression is of wrong type" error.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a conditional insert `INSERT ... WHEN ...  THEN`, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PilotKeyLookup(
  p1id int, p2id int
);

INSERT INTO PilotKeyLookup VALUES( 5, null );
INSERT INTO PilotKeyLookup VALUES( 6, 7 );

CREATE TABLE BridgeTable(
   groupid int, pilotid int
);

CREATE SEQUENCE sqBridgeGroupID;

INSERT
  WHEN 1 = 1 THEN INTO BridgeTable( groupid, pilotid ) 
                  VALUES ( sqBridgeGroupID.nextval, p1id )
  WHEN p2id is not null THEN INTO BridgeTable( groupid, pilotid ) 
                  VALUES ( sqBridgeGroupID.currval, p2id )
SELECT *
FROM PilotKeyLookup p;



select * from BridgeTable;

   GROUPID    PILOTID
---------- ----------
         1          5 
         2          6 
         2          7
```

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. I decided to choose this solution, because it seemed to work faster than the one below.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem in your code

1) use `x.p1id`instead of subquery and

2) sorry this `x.p2id != null`doesn't work ... **IS NOT null* s´must be used!

This works ...

```
declare
begin
for x in (select * from PilotKeyLookup) loop
if x.p2id is  not null then
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.nextval, x.p1id);
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.currval, x.p2id);
else
insert into BridgeTable (groupid, pilotid) values (sqBridgeGroupID.nextval, x.p1id);
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

... but you should definitively use a solution without a cursor loop as proposed in other answer.

As a exersize you may compare the performce of the two approaches with some nontrivial data amount and you will see why it is a good idea to avoid the loop (if it is possible).

Comment: Thanks, it worked, too, but I chose the solution above without the loop, because that seemed to work faster.

Comment: That is definitively the correct choice. I only documented how to **not to do it** correctly...